# Modifier keys when working remotely are broken / lazy

Tags: keyboard, remote-desktop, screen-sharing, remote-control, apple-remote-desktop

I work a lot from home, using screen-sharing to control my remote Mac mini from my (local) MBP laptop, or my customers' machines using ARD (or even TeamViewer).

Recently I've started having problems with the modifier keys (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd> ) - maybe since upgrading to macOS Sierra, but I'm not sure.

## The problem

It seems to me that the transfer of the modifier key state to the remote machine has changed - and has become "lazy".

By this I mean:

- **Before**: As soon as I pressed a modifier key, this was immediately reflected on the remote machine.
- **Now**: The state of the modifier key is only changed on the remote machine when I **also** press a normal key.

## This means that...

- trying to perform a mouse action (click / drag) with modifier keys **does not work anymore**
- modifier keys get stuck in a particular state until I press another key to free them up
- doing remote work has become very difficult.

## The question is:

It seems to be a bug/defect.  Does anybody have a fix/workaround to this weird modifier key behavior?

Comment: I have recently experienced this problem on a colleagues computer too, which indicates that this is not a special problem of my personal setup, but is really a problem of the software (which bit exactly I do not know)

Comment: I am seeing this too and submitted a radar://38910378

Answer (score 1):

I've been using MBP for quite a while and researched such problems often, as I come from the Windows world, so generally I need to do some modifications to get used to it.

Recently I was curious if any alternative exist for [Karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/), but this similar thread refers also to Karabiner: https://superuser.com/a/263719/594221

Indeed, I haven't found any stable tool like this to workaround such problems.